# Java: How to insert a N:M association table

Tags: java, mysql, algorithm, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm wondering what would be the best algorithm (couldn't find any java best practices documentation about this) to insert data in a association table from a N:M relationship.

For Example, a many to many relationship like "a teacher has many students and a student has many teachers" that requires a association table like Teacher_Student with the three usual fields like teacher_id, student_id and date.

In my case I keep, for not-db-related reasons, an array with the teachers in the student object and viceversa, an array of students in the teacher object.

What do you guys think is the best java algorithm to insert this in sql?

Any pseudocode or a link to some documentation would be great. Thank you all for your advice.

Comment: I don't really understand what algorithm you're looking for. You just need a loop which inserts N rows in a table. Where's the difficulty?

Comment: I was referring to something like:

if (there's no pair teacher_id - student_id in the associated table)  
{  
 if (this teacher is not inserted)  
 {  
  insert teacher  
 }  
 if (this student id not inserted)  
 {  
  insert student  
 }  
 insert both ids in the associated table  
}

Answer (score 0):

```
for each student s
  for each teacher t in the s array of teachers
    insert t, s, date
```

Of course, this could equally well be done the by iterating over the teachers, inserting a record for each student in the teacher's array of students. That is a symptom of the non-normalized form of the internal data.